# android -Material Design not effecting android

Tags: android

I want to use material design for my application . I create a new project .

in gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XXXXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

styles:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

values-21->styles:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I don't see any reason why it's not working . When I run my application on emulator api 21 , this is the result :
[image]

this is the pre android 5 :

[image]

as you can see, the colorPrimaryDark is not working at .

What am I doning is wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the emulator runs on API 21? It looks more like 19 (KitKat) where colorPrimaryDark won't color the status bar.

Comment: colorPrimaryDark will work on API 22(5.1.1)